# Add fixed MapLayer once

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary

In my application I have a map for which the first thing I do (on launching) is to add a custom MapLayer (which I populate with many MapOverlays/pushpins).

When I browse to another page of the app and then return to the map page, everything (ie the MapLayer that was drawn on my map) is gone.

It takes time to add it all over again each time the user navigates to the map page so I would like it to be fixed, drawn/added just once.

Any suggestions?

edit, added the code [I removed some details, the structure remains the same]:

```
private async void drawStations()
        {

            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("stasy.sqlite");

            List<line1_stations> lines = await conn.QueryAsync<line1_stations>("select *...");

            Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer layer = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer();

            Pushpin p;

            foreach (line1_stations a in lines)
            {
                double sLat = Convert.ToDouble(a.lat);
                double sLon = Convert.ToDouble(a.lon);

                p = new Pushpin();
                p.Location = new GeoCoordinate(sLat, sLon);
                p.Tap += img_Tap;
                p.Content = "...";
                p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                p.Width = 30;
                p.Height = 30;

                MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
                overlay1.Content = p;
                overlay1.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(sLat, sLon);
                overlay1.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
                layer.Add(overlay1);
            }

            myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
        }
```

Comment: could you share code, where you trying to add pushpin in map.

Comment: Added code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Call drawStations method in page's constructor

Comment: That's what I do now. But I want that method to be called just once each time the app in launched and then have the MapLayer fixed in the map. Calling this method everytime the user navigates to this page will need too much time.

Comment: I just post a ans, give a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create your MapLayer as a public property in App.xaml.cs and set it only when your app is running first time.

Then create an instance of app inside page with your map and add your MapLayer to your Map layers inside [OnNavigatedTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.onnavigatedto%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) event.

Comment: Could you provide the code for your second sentence?

Answer (score 0):

Define a flag in app level. here is the sample

```
// In App.xaml.cs
public static bool IsLaunched = false;
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
        {
           IsLaunched =true;
        }

//In your map screen

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
         if(App.IsLaunched)
           {
             drawStations();
             //Set App flage to false
             App.IsLaunched = false;
           }
        }

private async void drawStations()
        {

            SQLiteAsyncConnection conn = new SQLiteAsyncConnection("stasy.sqlite");

            List<line1_stations> lines = await conn.QueryAsync<line1_stations>("select *...");

            Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer layer = new Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls.MapLayer();

            Pushpin p;

            foreach (line1_stations a in lines)
            {
                double sLat = Convert.ToDouble(a.lat);
                double sLon = Convert.ToDouble(a.lon);

                p = new Pushpin();
                p.Location = new GeoCoordinate(sLat, sLon);
                p.Tap += img_Tap;
                p.Content = "...";
                p.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
                p.Width = 30;
                p.Height = 30;

                MapOverlay overlay1 = new MapOverlay();
                overlay1.Content = p;
                overlay1.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(sLat, sLon);
                overlay1.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 1.0);
                layer.Add(overlay1);
            }

            myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
        }
```

Comment: I have already tried that. The problem is that all that is drawn in the map (calling drawStations) is lost after navigating in another page of the app. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Because when you navigating back to your map page,all page control are reinitialize and you lost complete work what you have done before .